# How do I use a test database when doing E2E NextJS tests with Cypress?

Tags: testing, next.js, cypress

I'm writing a NextJS app hosted in Vercel and I'm trying to add Cyprus end to end tests without polluting my production data

The way I'm running these tests is the following two commands:

`cypress open` to open Cypress

`prisma generate && next dev` to run my project

At the moment (advised by the docs) I have a `.env.local` file which is working I've attempted a `.env.test` file but the environment variables weren't being pulled through to Cypress or the NextJS app

I've spent a lot of time looking to see how to run a NextJS app with a different environment file and not had a lot of luck

Any suggestions would be fantastic. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a repo? I feel there's a lot of detail missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step would be to create a new test database that is separate from your production database. You can use the same schema as your production database, but this should be a separate instance to avoid polluting your production data.
Make sure it does not include any sensitive/confidential data.

That way, you can create a `.env.test` file, with `DATABASE_URL` pointing to your *test* database.

You can then use the [`cross-env` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) to help you manage environment variables across different environments. (`npm install --save-dev cross-env`). Or consider [more recent alternatives](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env#other-solutions), since `cross-env` works, but is in "maintenance" mode.

Modify your scripts in `package.json` to use the `cross-env` package to set the `NODE_ENV` to `test` when running tests, and to use the `.env.test` file. You can set this up using `next dev -p 3001`, where 3001 is a different port than your normal development one.
Your `scripts` section of your `package.json` might look like:

```json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test next dev -p 3001",
  "cypress:open": "cypress open"
}
```

In your `next.config.js` file, configure Next.js to load the correct `.env` file based on the `NODE_ENV`.
For example, you can do this:

```js
const { PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER } = require('next/constants')

module.exports = (phase) => {
  const env = {}

  switch (phase) {
    case PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER:
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
        // When running Cypress tests
        env.DATABASE_URL = process.env.TEST_DATABASE_URL
      } else {
        // When running `npm run dev`
        env.DATABASE_URL = process.env.DEV_DATABASE_URL
      }
      break
    // more cases for other environments...
  }

  return {
    env,
    // other Next.js config here...
  }
}
```

In your Cypress `cypress.json` configuration file, ensure it points to the test server URL. If your local development is running on port 3000, your test should be on a different one, like 3001.
For instance:

```json
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:3001"
}
```

Finally, you can open two terminal windows.

- In the first one, run `npm run test` to start your Next.js app in test mode, pointing to your test database.
- In the second one, run `npm run cypress:open` to start Cypress and execute your tests.

Remember to regenerate your Prisma client after switching the database URL by running `prisma generate` if you are using Prisma.

Make sure that your test database is in the correct state before each test run. You might need to seed data before tests, or clean up after them. Look into `beforeEach` and `afterEach` hooks in Cypress for executing code before and after each test or suite of tests, as documented in [Cypress / Writing and Organizing Tests](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests).

Note: you might *not* want to commit your `.env.test` file to the version control system. It should be added to `.gitignore` file. Instead, provide a `.env.test.example` file with the needed environment variables without the real values.

Comment: `cross-env` solved the problem, thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you `cross-env` working fine, loads the correct environment variables from `.env.test.local` :)